# symlink function creating a dead link

Tags: perl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Enter link name\n";
chomp(my $link = <STDIN>);

my $link1;
$link1 = readlink '/home/test/abc_test/xyz';

symlink("$link1", "/home/test/test_scripts/$link");
```

/home/test/abc_test/xyz is pointing to a directory like below:

```
cd /home/test/abc_test
ls -lrt
xyz -> dir
```

In `$link` I am taking value of symlink name from the user, for example `"abc"`.

In the above script, I am trying to create a symlink in `/home/test/test_scripts` path that should point to the directory to which `xyz` is pointing to. The final result that I want that should create under `/home/test/test_scripts` is

```
abc -> dir
```

The above code is producing the same result but creating a deadlink in the path.

Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "deadlink in the path"? >> Means it is creating a deadlink which like "abc -> dir" in "/home/test/test_scripts" path which I cannot open.

Comment: when the target of a symbolic link doesn't start with `/`, it's relative to the dirname of symlink, not to the current working directory of the process which accesses it.

Comment: It's not clear why you want to make a symlink to the target of `/home/test/abc_test/xyz` instead of to `/home/test/abc_test/xyz` itself: `symlink '/home/test/abc_test/xyz', "/home/test/test_scripts/$link" or die "symlink: $!"`

Comment: Re "*The final result that I want that should create under /home/test/test_scripts is `abc -> dir`*", That's what you are getting with the code you posted. It seems that what you actually want is `abc -> /home/test/abc_test/dir`. That said, `abc -> /home/test/abc_test/xyz` would work just as well, so you don't even need to use `readlink`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `readlink` returns just the directory name, `dir`, not the full path to `dir`.

I assume you do not run your script within the directory containing `dir`. In that case, you need to provide the full path to both arguments of [symlink](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/symlink.html):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $link = 'abc';
my $link1 = readlink '/home/test/abc_test/xyz';
my $x = symlink "/home/test/abc_test/$link1", "/home/test/test_scripts/$link";
print "$x\n";
```

I also show that you can inspect the return value of `symlink` to see if it succeeded (1) or not (0).

Comment: Thanks all for your help. This is returning the relative path only but is there any way that I can get only the directory that 'xyz' is pointing to let's say 'dir1' rather than "/home/test/abc_test/dir1" ?

Comment: @toolic the code you sent is creating the below result:

abc -> /home/test/abc_test/test1 (suppose xyz is pointing to the directory "test1")

The result I need is as below:

abc -> test1